# stack bootstrap column vertically

Tags: html, bootstrap-grid

i am trying to make a responsive website, a blog but i have a problem that am experiencing, the bootstrap grid i have col-lg-4 per blog but they vary in height and it follows a pattern by maintaining the same line of column, but i would like to remove the extra spaces. hope anyone around could help.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4" style="height: 200px"> i am a div of height 
      200px</div>
      <div class="col-lg-4" style="height: 400px"> i am a div of height 
      400px</div>
      <div class="col-lg-4" style="height: 300px"> i am a div of height 
      300px</div>
      <div class="col-lg-4" style="height: 500px"> i am a div of height 
      500px</div>
   </div>
</div>


row{ display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap}
```

My current blog structure
[image]

The way i want it to be

[image]

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using?

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming you are using the latest BS version. If so, you should take a look at:

[**Card columns**](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#card-columns)

> *Cards can be organized into [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/)-like columns with just CSS by wrapping them in .card-columns. Cards are built with CSS column properties instead of flexbox for easier alignment. Cards are ordered from top to bottom and left to right.*

Here is the example from the docs

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
    
<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/300" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card p-3">
    <blockquote class="card-block card-blockquote">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer>
        <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/300" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-inverse card-primary p-3 text-center">
    <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>
      <footer>
        <small>
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/300" alt="Card image">
  </div>
  <div class="card p-3 text-right">
    <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer>
        <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for replying, using your answer gives me what i want, but i have found a plugin for that

Comment: notice that card-columns have been dropped from BS 5. any alternative there?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the UI design you are looking for

```
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="row">
              BLOG 1
          </div>
          <div class="row">
             BLOG 4
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            BLOG 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            BLOG 3
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

i have found the way out, maybe try this plugin
https://masonry.desandro.com/

```
<div class="row grid">
<div class="col-lg-4 grid-item">...</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 grid-item">...</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 grid-item">...</div>
...
</div>
```

Using the masonry plugin with jquery

```
$('.grid').masonry({
 // options
 itemSelector: '.grid-item',
});
```

using the masonry plugin with plain js

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.grid');
var msnry = new Masonry( elem, {
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
});
```

that's all you need to do